# How to set a CSS::before image source from a data attribute?

Tags: css

Is it possible in CSS to set an element's `::before` content to a url passed as a data-attribute?

For example, if I have a bunch of testimonials and testimonial "headshots", I'm trying to pass them to CSS like so:

### PHP / HTML:

```php
$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image)[0];


echo '
    <div class="testimonial fp-card content-section content-section--has-center-image" data-image="' . $image_src . '">
       <div class="testimonial__text">' . $text . '</div>
    </div>';
```

### SCSS:

```
.testimonial {
  &::before {
    content: attr(data-image); // This outputs the string URL. How can I use the string URL as an actual URL?
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.5rem;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    // Etc
  }
}
```

Is there a way to pass the url from the `data-image` attribute to the `::before` content as a valid URL?

I tried `content: url(attr(data-image))`, but that didn't work.

Comment: you cannot, use CSS variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Is there a way to use this as an actual URL? I'm trying to pass the `var(--image-src)` into the `content: url(var(--image-src)), but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: no, the url() part need to belong to the variable as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS variables for this purpose.

You need to define a variable in CSS and assign a value to it through inline styles.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      .box {
        --avatar-url: "";

        position: relative;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: var(--avatar-url);
      }

      .box::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        top: 0;
        left: 200px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: var(--avatar-url);
      }
    </style>

    <div class="box" style="--avatar-url: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```